# Encoding issue with Apache , displaying diamond characters in browser

Tags: php, apache, encoding

Request you all to help me set up Apache server on Cent OS. It looks like some encoding issue, but I am not able to resolve it yet.

- Instead of HTML content it displays HTML source in (chrome,firefox), IE 9 works fine. It displays � character after each "<" symbol. 
  http://pdf.gen.in/index1.htm
- Second Problem is with PHP. It displays source code of PHP http://pdf.gen.in/index.php with similar diamond characters, wherever it encounters a "<" character. It seems like php issue is related to the first issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a decent text editor, and always set encoding of php/html to "UTF-8 without BOM".

Create a file named "test.php", paste below codes and save with "UTF-8 without BOM" encoding, then it will work just fine.

```php
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I didn't realized that the source files were saved in Unicode encoding.  I changed it to UTF-8 and it is working fine now.

Comment: @geekonweb UTF-8 is buggy with php, so ALWAYS use "UTF-8 without BOM".

Comment: What is "UTF-8 without BOM"? can you explain it a little? I usually use Textpad as code editor.

Comment: Hope this will help. I use notepad++ so it's quite convenient to set encodings. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Answer (score 1):

Those files are encoded with UTF-16LE. For the static HTML page, you might be able to get it to work by setting the charset correctly in the MIME type (it's currently `text/html; charset=UTF-8`). I don't know how strong PHP's Unicode support is. Try using UTF-8 instead, it's generally more well supported due to its partial overlap with ASCII.